# RegEx: extract everything until X where X is not between two braces

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex, that extracts everything after a given text (here, "HIT") until the next pipe symbol "|" which is NOT surrounded by "[[" and "]]".

Example-Text:

```
text | HIT = [[t1|t2]] moretext [[more braces]] | moretext | moretext
```

This is the regex I've tried:

```
HIT[ \t]*=(.[^\|]+)
```

Of course, this only returns "***HIT = [[t1***" but I am looking for a regex that returns "***HIT = [[t1|t2]] moretext [[more braces]]***".

Thanks for your kind support

Christian

Comment: Are your non-bracketed, 'terminating' pipes always surrounded by whitespace as in the example here?

Comment: I was looking for a solutions that works with PHP. Gumbos solution (see below) works perfectly with PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
HIT[ \t]*=((?:[^[|]|\[\[[^[\]]*]])*)
```

The `(?:[^[|]|\[\[[^[\]]*]])*` part matches

- any sequence of either any character except `[` and `|` (`[^[|]`), or
- a sequence of any character except `[` and `]` that is surrounded by `[[…]]` (`\[\[[^[\]]*]]`).

Comment: Gumbo, not only that the response was extremely fast it also is exactly what I was looking for and works perfectly! Thanks a lot for your help...

Comment: @itsame69: You’re welcome. Accepting my answer as *the* answer would also make it perfect for me. :)

Comment: hmmm... If you tell me how, I definitely would do that ;-). Sorry, I'm absolutely new here at stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok, I think I've just figgured out how to do that ;-)